# Что такое интринсики (intrinsics)?

Tags: c++, c, функции, терминология

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое интринсики?

Comment: [_Наряду с ассемблерными вставками используются интринсики, т.е. мнемонические аналоги ассемблерных команд._](http://mcst.ru/sistema_programmirovaniya)

Comment: Кстати, посмотрите тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tzkfha43.aspx И еще - например, в Open Watcom было можно указать, использовать ли реальный вызов для некоторых функций, или использовать intrinsic - по сути, готовый встраиваемый ассемблерный код.

Comment: можно где-то посмотреть на пример использования этого чуда?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow первым комментарием Grundy дал ссылку на наукообразную статью с этим термином в русской транскрипции. Там автор вводит термин и на всякий случай его поясняет.

Comment: @Arkady, перевод "присущий" вас устроит? Вполне логично, что в контексте функций и компиляторов имеет смысл говорить о "функциях, присущих данному компилятору".

Comment: @0andriy, мой вопрос был праздным. Просто я согласен с тезисами из комментария VladFromMoscow с одной стороны, а с другой осознал, что столкнись я с такой задачей, я бы поломал голову, как корректно это перевести, и стоит ли переводить.
И "присущий", имхо, по прежнему не очевидно) Пока мне кажется самым разумным не переводить термин, но и не использовать транслит.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268562/

Comment: Авось кому-то пригодится - [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/), из [статьи](https://algorithmica.org/ru/sse) о векторизации

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Вот конкретный пример из [VC++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tzkfha43.aspx).

```
#pragma intrinsic(strlen)
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << strlen(argv[0]);
}
```

Компилируем с отключенной оптимизацией (/Od). При наличии `#pragma intrinsic(strlen)` получаем

```
    mov eax, 4
    imul    ecx, eax, 0
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _argv$[ebp]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+ecx]
    mov DWORD PTR tv74[ebp], eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR tv74[ebp]
    add ecx, 1
    mov DWORD PTR tv77[ebp], ecx
$LL3@main:
    mov edx, DWORD PTR tv74[ebp]
    mov al, BYTE PTR [edx]
    mov BYTE PTR tv80[ebp], al
    add DWORD PTR tv74[ebp], 1
    cmp BYTE PTR tv80[ebp], 0
    jne SHORT $LL3@main
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR tv74[ebp]
    sub ecx, DWORD PTR tv77[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR tv70[ebp], ecx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR tv70[ebp]
    push    edx
    mov ecx, OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
```

А при отсутствии -

```
mov eax, 4
imul    ecx, eax, 0
mov edx, DWORD PTR _argv$[ebp]
mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+ecx]
push    eax
call    _strlen
add esp, 4
push    eax
mov ecx, OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@I@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
```

(Для информации - при включенной оптимизации одинаково в обоих случаях -

```
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _argv$[esp-4]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax]
    lea edx, DWORD PTR [eax+1]
    npad    7
$LL3@main:
    mov cl, BYTE PTR [eax]
    inc eax
    test    cl, cl
    jne SHORT $LL3@main
    sub eax, edx
    mov ecx, OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    push    eax
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@I@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
```

Т.е. в определенном смысле это inline-функции, только с заранее готовым ассемблерным кодом.

Comment: *в определенном смысле это inline-функции, только с заранее готовым ассемблерным кодом* - совсем доступно объяснили +1

Answer (score 42):

В С/С++ любая сущность, объявленная, но не определённая в пределах компилируемого файла считается внешней. Это относится и к функциям в не меньшей степени, к чем к переменным. Ссылки на внешние функции остаются в скомпилированном объектном файле и будут заменены на обращения к настоящим сущностям только на этапе линковки, если все межмодульные зависимости будут удовлетворены. Не существует никакой разницы между `PrivetVasya()` и `printf()` — с точки зрения компилятора обе абсолютно равнозначны и про обе можно сказать «да это просто какие-то внешние функции». Когда идиотские учебники или учителя-недоучки начинают говорить «встроенная функция языка printf()» (а это очень популярный бред) — надо понимать, что это просто глупость, что в язык ничего такого не встроено, что компилятор обрабатывает вызов к printf() на тех же условиях, что и вызов к любой другой функции, да хоть в соседнем файле реализованной. Что касается той же printf() — то это не встроенная функция языка, а функция стандартной библиотеки языка. Стандарт на язык эту функцию описывает, провозглашает её наличие в стандартной библиотеке, но сам компилятор к стандартной библиотеке отношения не имеет — она может появиться на этапе линковки, а может и вообще не появляться.

Тем не менее, есть поистине **встроенные функции**, для которых в компиляторе на самом деле реализована **особая обработка** — они называются intrinsic-ами. У разных компиляторов набор intrinsic-ов разный. Intrinsic-ом может быть и функция, которая штатно должна жить в стандартной библиотеке. При вызове intrinsic-функции компилятор генерирует особый код, характерный именно для данной функции: не генерируется никакого call-а, не будет никакого реального вызова и возврата, а будет несколько инструкций, выполняющих нужную задачу. Например очень распространённый intrinsic `memcpy()` компилируется не в вызов какой-то функции, а в инструкцию `repnz movs` (пример для x86).

Понятное дело, что в стандартной библиотеке С (libc) для AVR есть некоторые функции, которые обеспечивают задержку. Естественно, это полновесные функции, которые внутри крутят цикл. Если нужна задержка в 1—2 такта, то естественно,  такие тяжеловесные функции не подходят. Сделать задержку в 1 такт полноценной (и обыкновенной) функцией нельзя: даже если это будет совершенно пустая функция, инструкция `call` выполняется за 4 такта, и инструкция `ret` — ещё 4 такта, итого 8 тактов на вызов пустой функции.

Без малейшей лишней мысли понятно, что задержки в единицы тактов (меньше 8) могут быть реализованы только intrinsic-ами. И теперь, скрестив пальцы, спросим: а есть ли в **avr-gcc** delay-функции (функции задержки), выполненные как intrinsic-и? Действительно есть такой intrinsic — функция называется `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles()`.

Источник: [Фейл gcc (или назвался intrinsic'ом — полезай в оптимизатор)](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=49301]).

Comment: И оформлять цитатой [не буду](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4623/178988). Тем более, в одном из абзацев поменял пару слов.

Comment: И делать общим -- тоже? )

Comment: @AK, я переписал bb-коды на markdown и поменял одно предложение :)

Answer (score 15):

*Интринсики* — это функции, вызовы которых заменяются компилятором на некую внутрикомпиляторную магию. То есть вы думаете, что вызываете функцию, но на самом деле её не существует, и вместо неё напрямую подставляется некий машинный код вне зависимости от флагов оптимизации.

Comment: Arhadthedev, а почему тогда компилятор это не делает автоматически к примеру для каждой стандартной библиотечной функции ?

Comment: С точки зрения компилятора нет никаких стандартных функций. Он видит всего лишь вызов, например, strlen, реализованный где-то в другом месте. Что же там на самом деле - библиотечная функция или что-то одноименное пользовательское - станет известно сильно позже.

Answer (score 8):

*Intrinsic* - это обёртка над функциями, которая встроена в компилятор, в таком же виде, как и обычные функции. Иными словами можно сказать, что это механизм включения машинных инструкций в код.

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

1. [Intrinsic function (en WiKi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function)
2. [Встроенные объекты компилятора](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/26td21ds.aspx)
3. [What are intrinsics? (en SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268562/5275890)

Answer (score 5):

*Интринсиками* в терминологии С и С++ называются сущности (обычно функции), которые с одной стороны формально не являются частью ядра языка (т.е. формально это сущности библиотечного уровня), но семантика которых тем не менее досконально и исчерпывающе известна компилятору.

Например, с формальной точки зрения стандартная функция `strcmp` является обычной библиотечной функцией. Компилятор не знает об этой функции ничего, кроме информации, содержащейся в ее объявлении: список и типы параметров и тип возвращаемого значения. Компилятор не знает, чему равно `strcmp("abc", "abc")` и не знает, меняет ли функция `strcmp` глобальньую переменную `int vasya;`.

Однако в некоторых реализациях эта функция может быть *интринсиком*: компилятор может обладать исчерпывающей информацией о том, что именно делает и чего не делает эта функция и использовать эту информацию в процессе генерации кода и выполнения оптимизаций. Реализация, в которой `strcmp` является интриниском, знает, что вызов `strcmp("abc", "abc")` можно заменить на константу `0` и что функция `strcmp` не меняет никаких глобальных переменных.

Можно сказать, что интринсики в чем-то похожи на inline-функции. Так как компилятор всегда видит полное определение inline-функции, он теоретически может извлечь из этого определения полное знание о семантике этой функции. Но на этом сходство и заканчивается. В случае интринсиков компилятору не нужно ничего ниоткуда извлекать: полное знание о семантике интринсика уже изначально заложено в компилятор его авторами.