# Интринсик intrinsic(_BitScanForward)

Tags: c++

Как использовать интринсик

```
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanForward)
```

В моем коомпиляторе не поддерживает я библиотека `intrin.h`

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145805/cant-use-bitscanforward64 Ваш вопрос в стиле "у меня подземный стук", конечно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621239/10105

Comment: @0andriy прежде чем скидывать ссылку, просмотрите о чем там говориться. У меня проблема именно с тем, что библиотека не поддерживается

Comment: Если в вашем компиляторе нет такого интринсика, то либо в нём есть аналогичный (и вам нужно использовать его), либо аналогичного нет, и тогда вам не повезло. В любом случае, наличие интринсиков не гарантировано спецификацией языка.

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить в вопрос, откуда этот интринсик (от какого компилятора), и какой компилятор у вас.

Comment: Вот. @VladD дело говорит.

Comment: @VladD у меня clang++

Comment: @VladD gcc поддерживает данный интринсик?

Comment: Поддерживает. Там имена `__builtin_*()`.

Answer (score 1):

У gcc есть [аналогичный интринсик](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) `__builtin_ctz`. Согласно [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set), должен работать и в clang.

---

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb.aspx) на `_BitScanForward`:

> Search the mask data from least significant bit (LSB) to the most significant bit (MSB) for a set bit (1).
>
> Parameters
>
> [out] Index
>   Loaded with the bit position of the first set bit (1) found.
>
> Remarks
>
> If a set bit is found, the bit position of the first set bit found is returned in the first parameter. If no set bit is found, 0 is returned; otherwise, 1 is returned.

---

[Документация](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) на `__builtin_ctz` в gcc:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_ctz (unsigned int x)`
>
> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

---

Эти определения кажутся равносильными (но `_BitScanForward` возвращает результат через out-параметр, а не через возвращаемое значение), за исключением случая нулевого аргумента. В этом случае `_BitScanForward` возвращает нулевой результат. Для clang вам нужно либо проверять на 0 параметр, либо воспользоваться аналогичным `__builtin_ffs` (который возвращается результат на единицу больше).

Comment: Вот что выводит коомпилятор `source_file.cpp:5:0: warning: ignoring #pragma intrinsic  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma intrinsic (_BitScanForward)
 ^
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:25:37: error: ‘_BitScanForward’ was not declared in this scope
         _BitScanForward(&position, i); `

Comment: @Alone_Fox: Ну это понятно. `_BitScanForward` нету в clang, пользуйтесь `__builtin_ctz` вместо него.

Comment: это gcc, а не clang

Comment: @Alone_Fox: А зачем вам `#pragma`? Это раз. А во-вторых, посмотрите в описание функции. `__builtin_ffs` не является тупо прямой заменой `_BitScanForward`. У неё, например, один аргумент, а не два, как у `_BitScanForward`. Так что просто заменить `_BitScanForward` на `__builtin_ffs` не пойдёт, нужно включить голову и править код.