# Inline / intrinsic функции

Tags: c++, inline

В чем разница между inline и intrinsic функциями? C/C++

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621215/195342 inline же уже больше не про оптимизацию (встраивание), "cегодня inline - это про one definition rule, а не про inline expansion оптимизацию" (см., например, https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/561772/)

Comment: inline -- это то, что пишете вы и разрешаете-рекомендуете вставить компилятору в код без вызова этого блока как функции, а intrinsic -- это реализация некоторого кода авторами компилятора, синтаксически оформленная как вызов функции (но м.б. и реализована как функция)

Comment: @Harry Сейчас так из каждого утюга говорят, но на самом деле нет, про оптимизацию тоже: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/inline-hints/